# MATLAB: Copy the first n elements of a vector, then skip n elements, then copy the next n elements

Tags: matlab, vector

Vector `x` is *2000*-by-*1*

I would like to take the first `20` elements of vector `x` and copy them to vector `y`, then copy the next `20` elements of vector `x` to vector `z`, then copy the next `20` elements to vector `y`, and so on.

I understand I could do this with a loop, but am hoping to find a more efficient method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be achieved by reshaping the vector to a matrix, selecting odd/even columns and finally flattening the matrix:

```
 m = reshape(a, 20, []);
 x = m(:,1:2:end); x = x(:);
 z = m(:,2:2:end); z = z(:);
```

Comment: This idea is good, but last I checked, Matlab doesn't allow subscripting function results.  Some additional temporary variables may be needed.

Comment: When I have 2000x1 vector named 'a', this seems to throw the error message "Error: ()-indexing must appear last in an index expression.". Do you know why that is?

Comment: OK, octave allows that.

Comment: `m = reshape(a, [20, 50]);` will throw an error as well as `20*50 ~= 20*100`. Also `m(:,1:2:end)(:)` is still invalid MATLAB syntax